# Angular 4 - ng2-dragula

Tags: angular, ng2-dragula

I'm trying to use [ng2-dragula](https://github.com/valor-software/ng2-dragula) to accomplish something like this (please ignore the design, I just trying to find a solution for the functionality):

[image: categories with sub categories]

I need to sort, both parent categories and sub categories. But I'm having some issues trying to make it both work, since I need to have the sub category within the parent category, otherwise I will get an undesired dragula behavior:

```
<ul
  *ngFor="let category of categories"
  [dragula]='"categories"'
  dragulaName="categories">

  <li
    class="parent-draggable"
    id="{{ category.id }}">

    #{{category.id}} :: {{ category.name }}

      <ul *ngIf="category.subCategories.length > 0"
          [dragula]="category.subCategories.dragulaName"
          [attr.dragulaName]="category.subCategories.dragulaName">

        <li
          *ngFor="let subCategory of category.subCategories"
          id="{{ subCategory.id }}">

            #{{subCategory.id}} :: {{ subCategory.name }}

        </li>

      </ul>
  </li>

</ul>
```

Here's a demo of what I've right now:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular4-dragula

Anyone is able to help?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: To clarify: you want to be able to drag the top level categories to reorder them, and you also want to be able to drag the sub categories within a parent category to reorder those too? Do you also want to drag sub categories between parent categories?

Comment: Hey @Rup.  you want to be able to drag the top level categories to reorder them:: YES.  also want to be able to drag the sub categories within a parent category to reorder those too:: YES  Do you also want to drag sub categories between parent categories:: NO.
I've kind of achieve it, but it when trying to sort a sub category, the drag event fires for the parent category also.